# QuickSort exercise

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, quicksort

I need to quickSort this: **90** 8 7 56 123 235 9 1 653 , being the pivot 90. I've seen many people doing it and I feel like everyone does it in a different way. I know how to do it if it were in the last position, following:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

but how would it be if it is at the beginning? Also what if it where in the middle?

Note: no code, just the nombers.

Thank you!

Note: This is what I had but I think it's wrong, is it?

653 8 7 56 123 235 9 1 **90** (Swap with last)

653 8 7 56 123 235 9 1 90 (arr[J] <= pivot? No, so J =0 and check next index)

8 653 7 56 123 235 9 1 90 (Swap)

8 7 653 56 123 235 9 1 90

8 7 56 653 123 235 9 1 90

8 7 56 9 123 235 653 1 90

8 7 56 9 1 235 653 123 90

8 7 56 9 1 90 653 123 235

8 7 56 9 1

Answer (score 0):

Initial data:
`90 8 7 56 123 235 91 653`

We select pivot at 90, the left marker to 9, and the right marker to 653.

`90 8 7 56 123 235 91 653
P  L                   R`

We increment the index of the left marker until we reach a value >90. The left marker is set to 123.
`90 8 7 56 123 235 91 653
P           L           R`

We decrement the index of the right marker until we reach a value <90. The right marker is set to 56.

`90 8 7 56 123 235 91 653
P        R  L`

The right marker and left marker have crossed, and thus we find a split point. We swap 90 with 56. 
`56 8 7 90 123 235 91 653`

We now have our pivot `90` in the correct position and recursively apply the quicksort to each of the partitions with a stopping case of a partition with a size of one.

`56 8 7 90 123 235 91 653
 P  L R  F  P   L      R`

('F' indicates the value is fixed to that index position)

This is a great resource on quicksort: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html

Comment: I saw a video on YouTube doing it that way and I thought it was easy, but then on the link above on geeksforgeeks, they do it differently. They kind of only check for 1 side, not both sides. Which one is correct?

Comment: Yes, the GeeksforGeeks `partition()` works differently than the InteractivePython algorithm. I am not sure which one is considered correct or if there is a single correct version of QuickSort. The important part is that they share the same base logic -- recursively (or iteratively) identify pivots and place them in index locations such that all elements "to the left" are less than the pivot and all values "to the right" are greater than the pivot.